# Predictive models to predict sales with r

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, predictive-models, random-forest

I would like to find a good model to predict which client will buy my product in 2018. I would like to have opinions on which method can fit my data to predict which client will the product A in 2018.

I have the following data:

```
client buyproductin17 buyproductin16 buyproductin15 all_day  day_cnt product 
 22         1               0              1           34      5       2
 23         0               1              1           56      11      2
 24         1               1              1           122     45      3
```

client = client ID

buyproduct17 = if the client buy the product A in 2017 or not

buyproduct16 = if the client buy the product A in 2016 or not

buyproduct15 = if the client buy the product A in 2015 or not

all_day = total number of day the client spent with all my product

day_cnt = total number of day the client spent with product A

product = total number of product A the client has

My first thought are a logistic regression model or a random forest. But which dependant variable can I use ? buyproductin17 ?

Thanks a lot

Dany

Comment: How many years of data do you have?

Comment: Is just a screenshot at a certain period of one day. Is the situation the 10/11/17

Comment: You can not fit statistical model just any table you have. Your data need transformation and feature engineering to create binary column where every product name was sold or not. Then you can use this column as response in your log regression.